# How to write to array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash

Does somebody know what is wrong and why it doesn't want to add all permutations in function into an array "array" and when I run for loop only gives me last value

```
#!/bin/bash
array=()
permutation() {

  local items="$1"
  local out="$2"
  local i
  [[ "$items" == "" ]] && array[$i]="$out" && return
  for (( i=0; i<${#items}; i++ )) ; do
    permutation "${items:0:i}${items:i+1}" "$out${items:i:1}"
  done
  }

permutation $1

for i in "${array[$i]}"
do 
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Where do you set `$2`?

Comment: You re-initialize the global `array` variable every time you enter the function. Move `array=()` outside of the function.

Comment: @cyrus, in the recursive `permutation` call within the function.

Comment: I moved array=() out and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `array+=( "$out" )` to append to the end of your array without needing to know the index of that value. Because you're declaring `i` local, it isn't shared across the invocations of your functions, so they're all overwriting `${array[0]}`.
2. `for i in "${array[$i]}"; do` ignores all the values of your array except for whichever one is in position `$i`, for the single value of `i` that exists *before* your `for` loop is entered. Use `for i in "${array[@]}"` to iterate over all values in the array.

See a corrected version of your code running at https://ideone.com/zIYigA